# How to set default value in dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

1.Create react component - customhtmlelement

```
<customelement>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.customHtml }} />
</customelement>
```

2.use of react component

```
<customhtmlelement
 customHtml="<input value={value} disable='true' placeholder='Enter text' type='text' id='test'</input>"/>><<customhtmlelement/>
```

set default value in text box.

```
let value= "test";
```

it's not working.
How to set default value in `innerHtml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you render input with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Anyway your code is not really valid.

Try this:

```
function CustomHTMLElement(props) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.customHtml}} />
}

function App() {
  const value = 'Test Value'

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomHTMLElement
        customHtml={`<input id='test' type='text' placeholder='Enter text' value='${value}' disabled=${true} />`}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, It may help

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const value = "test";

// inner HTML Example...
function createMarkup() {
  return {
    __html: "<input value="+value+" disable='true' placeholder='Enter text' type='text' id='test'</input>"
  };
}

//React component...
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use like this, with the help of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

let value = "text";

function CustomHtmlElement(props) {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.customHtml }} />;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomHtmlElement
        customHtml={`<input value=${value} disable='true' placeholder='Enter text' type='text' id='test'</input>`}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[working example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59243501-so-kfgix)